# Fastest way to compare 2 objects in js

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

Which is the fastest way to compare 2 objects in javascript?

For example I have these 2 objects:

```
a = [{'name': 'john', 'age': 22}, {'name': 'mike', 'age': 23}, {'name': 'anne', 'age': 12}, {'name': 'dan', 'age': 29}, {'name': 'jane', 'age': 34}]
b = [{'name': 'john', 'age': 22}, {'name': 'anne', 'age': 12}]
```

Normally, I would do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
        console.log(a[i]) // => [{'name': 'john', 'age': 22}, {'name': 'anne', 'age': 12}]
    }
}
```

This is taking too long, is it there another way faster? Thank you for your time!

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? Do you want to see if they're exactly identical? If so, you could do `JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)`.

Comment: Those are arrays of objects. What do you exactly want to compare? Arrays or objects?

Comment: Basically I want to check if an item from `a` is in `b`, then set a value `a[i].checked = true`

Comment: @RobertAKARobin Don't do that as `JSON.stringify({a:1,b:1}) === JSON.stringify({b:1,a:1})` is implementation-dependent (note the changed property order).

Comment: With the data structure you've got, you'll have to iterate through the arrays. For a more efficient algorithm, choose a better data structure.

Comment: Creating a hashmap(s) would be more efficient

Comment: Your title is misleading, you're not actually comparing 2 objects in JS you seem to be looking for a way to compute the union (or intersection) of two arrays. Maybe [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is more suitable

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can have a look at the [fast-deep-equal](https://github.com/epoberezkin/fast-deep-equal) package. Here is a performance benchmark from their README.md for your reference.

```
fast-deep-equal x 226,960 ops/sec ±1.55% (86 runs sampled)
nano-equal x 218,210 ops/sec ±0.79% (89 runs sampled)
shallow-equal-fuzzy x 206,762 ops/sec ±0.84% (88 runs sampled)
underscore.isEqual x 128,668 ops/sec ±0.75% (91 runs sampled)
lodash.isEqual x 44,895 ops/sec ±0.67% (85 runs sampled)
deep-equal x 51,616 ops/sec ±0.96% (90 runs sampled)
deep-eql x 28,218 ops/sec ±0.42% (85 runs sampled)
assert.deepStrictEqual x 1,777 ops/sec ±1.05% (86 runs sampled)
ramda.equals x 13,466 ops/sec ±0.82% (86 runs sampled)
The fastest is fast-deep-equal
```

Answer (score 17):

I don't have enough rep to add a comment to explain [Neha Mundra's answer [below]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61430543/8112776) so thought I'd post instead.

```
let a={a:20,b:10};
let b={b:10,a:20};

console.log(Object.entries(a).sort().toString()===
            Object.entries(b).sort().toString()) //true
```

1. **`Object.entries(a)`** / **`Object.entries(b)`** returns the contents of the objects
2. **`.sort()`** orders them by key value (`a`/`b`), as you can see in the example the keys are reversed when declared, this will ensure they are in the same order for comparison.
3. **`.toString`** returns a string representation of the object.
4. The `===` operator is checking for equality of both strings.

Hope that might help someone. This can also be checked in your browsers dev console, if you're not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 6):

```
let a={a:20,b:10};
let b={b:10,a:20};

console.log(Object.entries(a).sort().toString()===
            Object.entries(b).sort().toString()) //true
```

Comment: can also add few lines of text talking about the solution which you have provided

Comment: Yes. Please provide a simple explanation of what the code is doing to help the OP wrap their head around the solution. Thanks!

Comment: It should be noted that this will _not_ work for objects deeper than one key, for instance. the following would fail:
{a:20,b:{a1:'1', a2:'2'}};

Answer (score 2):

This should work (written in TS) if you don't want to use one of the other options, it even works with deep comparison but you might want to write a few tests for it :)

`compareOrder` param can be used for example: if `obj2` was an *implementation* of an interface that may have additional things such as methods added beyond its interface, but you only care that items in `obj1` exist in `obj2`, not that they are ordered the same. For example, if you have a class that implements an interface (e.g. `obj2` was a class based on an interface of the structure of `obj1`), but you only care about the properties existing on `obj1` (e.g. if `obj1` was Record<string, any>)

If you want to compare both the order *and* the items from both objects, and those objects are potentially implementations of an interface, you'd need to call it like so:
`deepCompare(obj1, obj2, true) && deepCompare(obj2, obj1, true)`

Calling it with `deepCompare(obj1, obj2)` is enough to say: the properties on `obj2` exist and are the same as `obj1` but I don't care if there are extra properties in `obj2`

Calling with `deepCompare(obj1, obj2, true) is the same as above, but the order matters.

```js
const deepCompare = (
    obj1: any,
    obj2: any,
    compareOrder: boolean = false
) => {
    if (typeof obj1 !== typeof obj2) return false;
    if ((typeof obj1 === "string" || typeof obj1 === "number") && obj1 !== obj2) return false;
    const o1 = Object.entries(obj1)
    const o2 = Object.entries(obj2)
    const compare = (first: [string, unknown][], second: [string, unknown][]) => {
        return first.every((value, index): boolean => {
            const secondIndex = second.findIndex(val => val[0] === value[0])
            if ((compareOrder && index !== secondIndex) || secondIndex === -1) return false;
            const [k1, v1] = value
            const [k2, v2] = second[secondIndex]
            if (k1 !== k2) return false;
            if (typeof v1 === "object" || typeof v2 === "object") return deepCompare(v1, v2);
            if (v1 !== v2) return false;
            return true;
        })
    }
    return compare(o1, o2)
}

deepCompare({1: {}}, {1: {}})
true
deepCompare({1: {2: {3: ""}}}, {1: {2: {3: "h"}}})
false
deepCompare({1: {2: {3: ""}}}, {1: {2: {3: ""}}})
true
deepCompare({1: {2: {3: ""}}}, {1: {2: ""}})
false
deepCompare({1: {}}, {1: ""})
false
deepCompare("123", "1")
false
deepCompare("123", 123)
false
deepCompare(123, 123)
true
deepCompare("123", [123])
false
deepCompare([123], [123])
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I  have tried And verified to compare any amount of deep level object

```js
function areObjectsEqual(obj1,obj2){
    if(typeof(obj1) !== 'object' || typeof(obj2) !== 'object'){
        return false;
    }

    let key1 = Object.keys(obj1)
    let key2 = Object.keys(obj2)
    
    if(key1.length !== key2.length){
        return false;
    }
    
    for( key of key1){
        
        if(!key2.includes(key)){
            return false;
        }
        
        value1 = obj1[key];
        value2 = obj2[key]
        
        if(typeof value1 === 'object' &&  typeof value2 === 'object'){
            if(!areObjectsEqual(value1,value2)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(value1 != value2){
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}

const objA = { a: 1, b: { c: 2 } };
const objB = { a: 1, b: { c: 2 } };
const objC = { a: 1, b: { c: 3 } };
const objD = { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: 4 }, e: 4 };
const objE = { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: 4 } ,e: 4 };
const objF = { x: 1, y: 2 };

console.log(areObjectsEqual(objA, objB)); // true (same values)
console.log(areObjectsEqual(objA, objC)); // false (different nested value)
console.log(areObjectsEqual(objA, objD)); // false (different nested key)
console.log(areObjectsEqual(objD, objE)); // true (same nested structure and values)
console.log(areObjectsEqual(objA, objF)); // false (different keys)
```

Answer (score -2):

Updating this, because my previous version didn't work, so here is now the function I currently use.

Can't tell if it's the fastest way to compare objects/arrays, but it's faster than `JSON.stringify()` comparison. Also you can speed up the process by setting depth limit.

**NOTE:**
**Both functions are depending on each other.**
**The code may overwrite some of your methods!**

```js
    /**
 * works like Array.isArray() but for objects
 * @return Boolean
 * @param object
 */
Object.isObject = function (object) {
    return object !== null && object instanceof Object && !Array.isArray(object)
}

    /**
     * compares arrays || non-mutator
     * @param Array array = []              -> array to compare with
     * @param Boolean valuesSequence = true -> take into consideration the order of values INHERITABLE
     * @param Integer depth = comparison depth of nested array
     * @return Boolean
     */
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'equalsCollection', {
        value: function (array, valuesSequence = false, depth = 999){
            if(!array || !(Array.isArray(array))) return false

            if(this.length !== array.length) return false

            if(--depth < 0) return true

            for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (valuesSequence) {
                    if ((Array.isArray(array[i]) && Array.isArray(this[i])) || (Object.isObject(array[i]) && Object.isObject(this[i]))) {
                        if (array[i].equalsCollection(this[i], valuesSequence, depth) !== true) return false
                    }
                    else if (array[i] !== this[i]) return false
                }
                else {
                    if(Array.isArray(array[i]) || Object.isObject(array[i])){
                        if(this.some(v => {
                            return array[i].equalsCollection(v, valuesSequence, depth)
                        }) !== true) return false
                    }
                    else if(!(this.includes(array[i]))) {
                        return false
                    }
                }
            }
            return true
        },
        writable: true,
    })

    /**
     * compares arrays || non-mutator
     * @param Array array = []              -> array to compare with
     * @param Boolean valuesSequence = true -> take into consideration the order of values INHERITABLE
     * @param Integer depth = comparison depth of nested array
     * @return Boolean
     */
     
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'equalsCollection', {
        value: function (array, valuesSequence = false, depth = 999){
            if(!array || !(Array.isArray(array))) return false

            if(this.length !== array.length) return false

            if(--depth < 0) return true

            for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (valuesSequence) {
                    if ((Array.isArray(array[i]) && Array.isArray(this[i])) || (Object.isObject(array[i]) && Object.isObject(this[i]))) {
                        if (array[i].equalsCollection(this[i], valuesSequence, depth) !== true) return false
                    }
                    else if (array[i] !== this[i]) return false
                }
                else {
                    if(Array.isArray(array[i]) || Object.isObject(array[i])){
                        if(this.some(v => {
                            return array[i].equalsCollection(v, valuesSequence, depth)
                        }) !== true) return false
                    }
                    else if(!(this.includes(array[i]))) {
                        return false
                    }
                }
            }
            return true
        },
        writable: true,
    })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `compareObjects({1: {}}, {1: {}})` = `false`, your code doesn't work.

Comment: W8 I got updated version

Answer (score -6):

```js
a = [{'name': 'john', 'age': 22}, {'name': 'mike', 'age': 23}, {'name': 'anne', 'age': 12}, {'name': 'dan', 'age': 29}, {'name': 'jane', 'age': 34}]
b = [{'name': 'john', 'age': 22}, {'name': 'anne', 'age': 12}]

var areTheyEqual = JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b) ;

console.log('Are they equal: ' + areTheyEqual)
```

Comment: sequence of properties will yield different results which I don't think its accurate

Comment: This is not correct method to compare objects as serialised string have issues comparing  see this for example  a = {'name': 'john'};
b = {'name': 'john', 'age': undefined};
JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b) ; // true which is incorrect should be false