# Optimized way to compare single object with array of objects and return matched value object

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object

Parent array of Objects with multiple records

```
const parent = [{name : 'raman', class : 'bca', roll : 3},{school : 'raman2', class: 'bca', phone: 222},{city : 'raman', class: 'bca'},{name : 'daman', pincode: 122, class :'bca'}]

// Child object with a single record
const child = {name : 'daman', class :'bca'}
```

Having a 5K list of obj in parent array and in child single object is present.

keys are not the same in parent and child records
what is the optimized way of comparison

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to compare 2 objects in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54291729/fastest-way-to-compare-2-objects-in-js)

Comment: Optimized for what? Speed? Memory usage? Energy consumed? Also, what are you comparing? How do you know what parent the child belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

As you only have one child to compare and you have to iterate all n parent objects your filter will always run in O(n) if you don't do anything weird.
5k objects shouldn't be a problem.

You can use a for-loop or e.g. do somthing like this:

```
let matches = parent.filter(p => p.class == child.class);
```

^^ I just guessed you want to match by the class property, otherwise you have to adapt this to your needs.

Comment: thanks.. I am exactly doing the same but p.class is not exactly the same with child(more or less entries of key and values) and p should contain all properties of child

Comment: How should the result look like for the example in your question?

Comment: parent object which contains all child entries.