# How can I go through two arrays and check if the information matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, comparison, booleanquery

I have two arrays of objects.
One with a json variable and one with an information variable.
The information variable is the one that should be equal to the json variable.
This is because, information is data from the front and json is data from the database, so I must check that this information is totally the same. In this case the example that I put in all are the same. But it is just for example.
So what should I do:

1. Compare the information variable with the json variable.
2. Start comparing data by data.
3. If the data is the same a message 'Everything went well' and if not 'there is an error'

I was trying it like this so that it goes through all the data but it throws me certain errors, such as the same element going through me twice.
I was reading that it can also be done with filter, I have seen a lot of documentation but I cannot implement it in my case.
Below in the code I show with whom to compare

```
 var json = [
{
  Transacción: "999999",
  Tarjeta: "0190",
  Tipo: "Contr ctdo",
  FechaDePago: "07/08/2022",
  Ventas: "-5.000,00",
  },
  {
   Transacción: "999997",
   Tarjeta: "0194",
    Tipo: "Contr ctdo",
   FechaDePago: "06/08/2022",
    Ventas: "4.000,00",
   },
   {
    Transacción: "999998",
     Tarjeta: "0195",
      Tipo: "Contr ctdo",
     "FechaDePago": "08/08/2022",
      Ventas: "6.000,00",
    },
   ];


var informacion = [
{
Trx: "Contr ctdo",
Fecha: "07/08/2022",
TermLoteCupon: "999999",
Tarj: "0190",
VentasconDto: "-5.000,00",
},
{
Trx: "Contr ctdo",
Fecha: "06/08/2022",
TermLoteCupon: "999997",
Tarj: "0194",
VentasconDto: "4.000,00",
},
{
Trx: "Contr ctdo",
Fecha: "08/08/2022",
TermLoteCupon: "999998",
Tarj: "0195",
VentasconDto: "6.000,00",
},
];

// The comparison should be that the data object array must be equal to the
  array of json objects.
 //The comparison is :
  //Trx must be equal to Tipo 
  //Fecha must be equal to FechaDePago
   //TermLoteCupon must be equal to Transacción
  // Tarj must be equal to Tarjeta
  //VentasconDto must be equal to Ventas
  // What I did was the following: 
 for (let i = 0; i < informacion.length; i++) {
     console.log('soy newarray', informacion[i]);
      for(let j = 0; j < json.length; j++){
        console.log('soy json parseado',json[j]);
         if(json[j] == informacion[i]){
           console.log('La informacion es compatible')
         }else{
           console.log('Hay error.')
          }
       }

       }
```

[image]

Comment: I think you're looking for a deep-equals.

Comment: Whether or not deep, what I want to see is one more idea of ​​what I did, to be able to implement it, even if it doesn't reach the answer, get a little closer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to compare 2 objects in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54291729/fastest-way-to-compare-2-objects-in-js)

Comment: I already saw this thread and it didn't help me much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP just ...

1. needs to implement a **comparison function** which returns a boolean value in case both passed transaction items (e.g. an item's key-value pair from the example's `informacion` array has to match its counterpart item of different key-value pairs from the example's `json` array) ...
2. ... and then needs to iterate the `informacion` array by [**`Array.prototype.every`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) while passing each currently processed `informacion` item together with its `json` counterpart-item where the latter is determined by the current `idx`-value.

As soon as the `every` based comparison process hits a mismatch, the iteration stops and returns the boolean `false` value whereas an uninterrupted full cycle means that all the requirements/conditions have been met, thus `every` returning the boolean `true` value.

```js
const json = [{
  Transacción: "999999",
  Tarjeta: "0190",
  Tipo: "Contr ctdo",
  FechaDePago: "07/08/2022",
  Ventas: "-5.000,00",
}, {
  Transacción: "999997",
  Tarjeta: "0194",
  Tipo: "Contr ctdo",
  FechaDePago: "06/08/2022",
  Ventas: "4.000,00",
}, {
  Transacción: "999998",
  Tarjeta: "0195",
  Tipo: "Contr ctdo",
  "FechaDePago": "08/08/2022",
  Ventas: "6.000,00",
}];

const informacion = [{
  Trx: "Contr ctdo",
  Fecha: "07/08/2022",
  TermLoteCupon: "999999",
  Tarj: "0190",
  VentasconDto: "-5.000,00",
}, {
  Trx: "Contr ctdo",
  Fecha: "06/08/2022",
  TermLoteCupon: "999997",
  Tarj: "0194",
  VentasconDto: "4.000,00",
}, {
  Trx: "Contr ctdo",
  Fecha: "08/08/2022",
  TermLoteCupon: "999998",
  Tarj: "0195",
  VentasconDto: "6.000,00",
}];

function hasMatchingTransactionValues(sample, proof) {
  return (
    sample.TermLoteCupon === proof['Transacción'] &&
    sample.VentasconDto === proof.Ventas &&
    sample.Fecha === proof.FechaDePago &&
    sample.Tarj === proof.Tarjeta &&
    sample.Trx === proof.Tipo
  );
}
function isMatchingTransactionData(sample, proof) {
  return (
    sample.length === proof.length &&
    sample
      .every((item, idx) =>
        hasMatchingTransactionValues(item, proof[idx])
      )
  );
}
console.log(
  'Does every transaction item match its counterpart ?..',
  isMatchingTransactionData(informacion, json),
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with filter:

```js
var json = [
    {
      Transacción: "999999",
      Tarjeta: "0190",
      Tipo: "Contr ctdo",
      FechaDePago: "07/08/2022",
      Ventas: "-5.000,00",
      },
      {
       Transacción: "999997",
       Tarjeta: "0194",
        Tipo: "Contr ctdo",
       FechaDePago: "06/08/2022",
        Ventas: "4.000,00",
       },
       {
        Transacción: "999998",
         Tarjeta: "0195",
          Tipo: "Contr ctdo",
         "FechaDePago": "08/08/2022",
          Ventas: "6.000,00",
        },
       ];
    
    
    var informacion = [
    {
    Trx: "Contr ctdo",
    Fecha: "07/08/2022",
    TermLoteCupon: "999999",
    Tarj: "0190",
    VentasconDto: "-5.000,00",
    },
    {
    Trx: "Contr ctdo",
    Fecha: "06/08/2022",
    TermLoteCupon: "999997",
    Tarj: "0194",
    VentasconDto: "4.000,00",
    },
    {
    Trx: "Contr ctdo",
    Fecha: "08/08/2022",
    TermLoteCupon: "999998",
    Tarj: "0195",
    VentasconDto: "6.000,00",
    },
    ];

    const result = json.filter((item, i) =>
        (item.Tipo === informacion[i].Trx) 
        && (item.FechaDePago === informacion[i].Fecha) 
        && (item.Transacción === informacion[i].TermLoteCupon) 
        && (item.Tarjeta === informacion[i].Tarj) 
        && (item.Ventas === informacion[i].VentasconDto)
    )

    console.log(result)

    if(result.length === json.length){
        console.log("it's equal");
    }else{
        console.log("it's not equal");
    }
```

Comment: With this what it does is verify everything? Because I changed a json data to see if it worked with the error and it keeps throwing me the same

Comment: yes it does. I changed the code to `if(result.length === json.length)`

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide a helper function which will compare these two particular objects - since the objects hold same values but the actual naming of the keys is different.

```
function isEqual(json, informaction) {
    return json.Transacción === informacion.TermLoteCupon &&
        json.Tarjeta === informacion.Tarj &&
        json.Tipo === informacion.Trx &&
        json.FechaDePago === informacion.Fecha &&
        json.Ventas === informacion.VentasconDto;
}
```

Then you use this helper function within your comparison instead of performing just a simple `json[j] == informacion[i]` comparison. This comparison is not possible with objects.

```
for (let i = 0; i < informacion.length; i++) {
    console.log('soy newarray', informacion[i]);
    for(let j = 0; j < json.length; j++){
        console.log('soy json parseado',json[j]);
        if(isEqual(json[j], informacion[i])) {
            console.log('La informacion es compatible')
        } else {
            console.log('Hay error.')
        }
    }
}
```

If the arrays are sorted in order (e.g. `informacion[0].id === json[0].id`) and you want to avoid comparing each value of `informacion` to each value of `json` you can do the following:

```
for(let i = 0; i < informacion.length; i++) {
    if(isEqual(json[i], informacion[i])) {
        console.log('La informacion es compatible')
    } else {
        console.log('Hay error.')
    }
}
```

if they are not, then you will have to figure out a way to loop through and compare them which suits your use-case.

Comment: I liked this idea a little more, it's very close to what I was looking for, it's just throwing me something wrong, instead of giving me a single time it multiplies them, if you want to see, edit the question with the sample image.

Comment: You have a nested for loop for checking so it will check `informacion.length * json.length` number of times - 3 * 3 = 9 in this case.

If you actually want to compare them in-order, take not of my edited answer.